# Concept-restricted range-based for loop of std::list<std::reference_wrapper<T>>

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++20, concept, reference-wrapper

I have some class `Foo` and a `std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>` and would like to iterate over its elements with a range-based for loop:

```
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};

int main() {
    std::list<Foo> ls = {{1},{2},{3},{4}};
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> refs(ls.begin(), std::next(ls.begin(),2));
    
    for(auto &foo : refs) {
        std::cout << foo.get().a << std::endl;
    }

    for(Foo &foo : refs) {
        std::cout << foo.a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice the additional `get()` when catching with `auto`, as we deduce type `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`, whereas in the second case `foo` is already implicitly converted to type `Foo&` as we explicitly catch with this type.

I was actually looking for a way to catch with auto but implicitly cast away the `std::reference_wrapper` implicitly in order to not have to bother with the `get()` method all the time in the `for` body, so I tried introducing a fitting concept and catching with this, i.e. I tried

```
//this is not legal code

template<typename T>
concept LikeFoo = requires (T t) {
    { t.a };
};

int main() {
    std::list<Foo> ls = {{1},{2},{3},{4}};
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> refs(ls.begin(), std::next(ls.begin(),2));

    for(LikeFoo auto &foo : refs) {
        std::cout << foo.a << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and hoped that it would work. `clang` however deduces the type of `foo` to `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`, so that in fact below code will be correct:

```
//this compiles with clang, but not with gcc

template<typename T>
concept LikeFoo = requires (T t) {
    { t.a };
};

int main() {
    std::list<Foo> ls = {{1},{2},{3},{4}};
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> refs(ls.begin(), std::next(ls.begin(),2));

    for(LikeFoo auto &foo : refs) {
        std::cout << foo.get().a << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, `gcc` completely refuses to accept the range-based for loop and complains `deduced initializer does not satisfy placeholder constraints`, as it tries to check `LikeFoo<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>`, which of course evaluates to false, so with `gcc` one cannot even catch `foo` concept-restricted. Two questions arise:

- **Which of the compilers is correct?** Should `LikeFoo auto& foo : refs` be valid?
- **Is there a way to *auto*-catch (possibly concept-restricted) `foo : refs` such that one can avoid having to write `get()` in the `for`-loop body?**

You can find this example at the [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/MoqesEf9K).

Comment: `auto` will always deduce the actual type. In order to get a `Foo&` an implicit conversion is needed. A concepts is a constraint on what type is allowed to be deduced. It can't apply conversions.

Comment: yes, thats what i thought as well, but is there a way to do this in the initialisation expression of the range-for-loop?

Comment: You can wrap `refs` in something that will automatically `get()` each element for you. But `for (auto& foo : unwrap_reference_wrapper(refs))` just looks like a more convoluted version of `for (Foo& : refs)`. It could have it's place in generic code though.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing tons of generic code, so this would be very useful. But I'm not sure how I would do that, without having to write a whole new iterator class etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Which of the compilers is correct? Should `LikeFoo auto& foo : refs` be valid?

No. `refs` is a range of `reference_wrapper<Foo>&`, so `foo` deduces to a reference to `reference_wrapper<Foo>` - which does not have a member named `a`. A constrained variable declaration doesn't change how deduction works, it just effectively behaves like an extra `static_assert`.

> Is there a way to auto-catch (possibly concept-restricted) `foo : refs` such that one can avoid having to write `get()` in the for-loop body?

Just by writing `refs`? No. But you can write a range adaptor to convert your range of `reference_wrapper<T>` to a range of `T&`. There is already such a thing in the standard library, `transform`:

```cpp
for (auto &foo : refs | std::views::transform([](auto r) -> decltype(auto) { return r.get(); })) {
```

That's a mouthful, so we can make it its own named adaptor:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto unwrap_ref = std::views::transform(
    []<typename T>(std::reference_wrapper<T> ref) -> T& { return ref; });
```

And then you can write either:

```cpp
for (auto &foo : refs | unwrap_ref) { ... }
for (auto &foo : unwrap_ref(refs)) { ... }
```

Either way, `foo` here deduces to be a `Foo`.

With a little bit more work, you can write a range adaptor that unwraps `reference_wrapper<T>` but preserves any other reference type.

Comment: by reading `constexpr`, do I interpret this correctly that `get()` is already applied there at runtime, so there will be no runtime difference compared to just `for (auto &foo : refs)` and then always getting the element? That would be great!

Comment: also, it appears to me that `clang` won't compile this currently

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bare minimum working example for a wrapper that calls `get` when being dereferenced.

```
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct reference_wrapper_unpacker {
    struct iterator {
        typename T::iterator it;

        iterator& operator++() {
            it++;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator& operator--() {
            it--;
            return *this;
        }

        typename T::value_type::type& operator*() {
            return it->get();
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) const {
            return it != other.it;
        }
    };
    reference_wrapper_unpacker(T& container) : t(container) {}

    T& t;
    
    iterator begin() const {
        return {t.begin()};
    }

    iterator end() const {
        return {t.end()};
    }
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};

int main() {
    std::list<Foo> ls = {{1},{2},{3},{4}};
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> refs(ls.begin(), std::next(ls.begin(),2));
    
    for(auto &foo : refs) {
        std::cout << foo.get().a << std::endl;
    }

    for(Foo &foo : refs) {
        std::cout << foo.a << std::endl;
    }

    for(auto &foo : reference_wrapper_unpacker{refs}) {
        std::cout << foo.a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To make it usable in generic code you would need to SFINAE to detect if the container actually has a reference_wrapper, and if not, just return the original container.

I'll leave that part out since it was not a part of the original question.